# How can I fix 0x00000057 error when installing Canon LBP2900 printer in a network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, drivers, printer

**Background**

I'm trying to install new Canon LBP2900 printer to all clients replacing HP LaserJet P1505 which connected to a printer server in small home network (4 computers). The details of network configuration provided as follows:

1. Printer server

   - OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit
   - IP address: 192.168.1.254
2. Client machines

   - OS: Same as printer server
   - IP address: 2 addresses defined (192.168.1.2 & 192.168.1.3)
3. Internet gateway

   - OS: Same as printer server
   - IP address: 192.168.1.1

**Condition**

LBP2900 driver installation in printer server and first client work smoothly without problems. But when trying to install same driver at second client, an error has occurred:

> Windows cannot connect to the printer. Operation failed with error
>   0x00000057.

What I've tried but doesn't seem to work:

1. Stopping and restarting "Print Spooler" service,
2. Checking Event Viewer log but found nothing about that error code,
3. Removing previously installed printers including network printer,
4. Opening Registry Editor, checking `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors` branch as suggested in [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/724736/cannot-delete-unwanted-com-ports-windows-7) but no `Canon` subkey exist,
5. Checking [a similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/750658/how-to-fix-error-0x00000057-when-installing-a-printer-driver-no-permission-to-w) but still not have any solution yet,
6. Starting remote connection (RDC) to printer server, then copying `cnab4stk.inf_x86_neutral_bbb022997b458100` folder with its contents from server's `FileRepository` to second client in `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository` folder as descibed in [this issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/itmanagement/en-US/a225d71c-be8b-4530-bf50-63001559a978/windows-can-not-connect-to-the-printer-0x00000057?forum=itmanager) after taking ownership & setting write permission to second client's admin account, however the error still persists.

How can I fix this driver installation problem?

Note: Both printer server & client firewall are temporarily disabled during printer driver installation to ensure no firewall problems.

Comment: Hi, just to ensure, the IP address of the printer is pingable on the second client? By the way, the question is kinda confusing the third time I read it, you mentioned that you have a Printer server, then why you are locally installing it per device? You should be sharing it right?

Comment: The ping works fine from second client to server. I installed printer driver on printer server, enabling printer sharing on it, then requesting driver installation on clients from printer server to make shared printer work on them, but only second client receive that error.

Comment: Hi, ohh yah I got it already, Canon really does ask (UAC like Yes or No) when you're mapping a shared printer. I got a good read from other forums as well and it points out to a registry issue. Could you do us a favor, try to login as a local or domain admin to the client laptop and try to access the share and then map the printer? Let us know if it gets mapped.

Comment: try cleaning up the drivers using *printui.exe /s /t2*